# Помогите элементарной регуляркой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно чтобы были только символы a-z A-Z 0-9 и длинна строки была от 5 до 30 символов (php)

```
$data = "mydata_81";
if (!preg_match('/[a-zA_Z0-9]/', $data)) echo 'False';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,30}$/', $data)) echo 'False';
```